# Como fazer uma div sumir e aparecer com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Sei que tem muitos tópicos falando sobre "como fazer uma div aparecer e sumir com JavaScript", a maioria deles ensinam a fazer:

```
document.getElementById('divaqui').style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementById('divaqui').style.visibility = 'visible';
```

Porém preciso fazer de uma maneira um pouco diferente
Eu apaguei todas as imagens (e div's dentro desta div `conteudo`) de uma div através desta function

```
function limpaConteudo()
{
    $(conteudo).empty() 
}
```

Agora preciso fazer uma das div's aparecer novamente dentro do `conteudo` que foi limpo.
 Não sei se fui clara. 
Podem me ajudar? Obg

```js
function limpaConteudo()
        {
          $(conteudo).empty() 
          document.getElementById('conteudo').style.background='#fff';
        }
```

```css
#conteudo{
      width:250px;
      height:250px;
      float:left;
      background-color:#ff1;  
      display: initial;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="conteudo" class="conteudo"> 
    <img src="https://png.icons8.com/view-as-different-user/ios7/50">
    </div>
    <div id="lixoLimpaConteudo">
     <img src="https://png.icons8.com/view-as-different-user/ios7/50" onclick="limpaConteudo()" alt="Limpar conteúdo">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Você quer restaurar o conteúdo uma vez limpo, você precisará ter ele armazenado em algum lugar, por favor insira o HTML junto a chamada dessa função para podermos te auxiliar :)

Comment: Está retornando um erro, mas basicamente, ele teria de sumir com a imagem da div conteudo e ao clicar novamente, deveria aparecer novamente a imagem. Diz que a $ não foi definida

Comment: O símbolo '$' indica uma chamada para a biblioteca JQuery, você está importando o JQuery?

Comment: Era isso que faltava, perdão, comecei a pouco tempo a estudar programação em Jscript, importei agora a biblioteca JQuery

Comment: Tem alguma maneira de fazer aquela imagem reaparecer? ou uma div dentro da div conteudo reaparecer??

Comment: Sora, mesmo com a biblioteca do jquery o código ainda só limpará a div. O comando empty remove o conteúdo. A menos que você tenha a imagem que você quer salva em outro lugar, você não terá como restaurar o conteúdo.

Comment: Entendi, vou tentar armazenar a imagem ou a div. Obg !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No caso você já tem a imagem na div id="lixoLimpaConteudo" então estou me baseando nela para "restaurar" o conteúdo, deixei o código comentado para melhor entendimento.

```js
function alteraConteudo(imagem)
{
  var novaImagem = "<img src='" + imagem.attr("src") + "' />"; //Crio uma nova imagem com mesmo src da clicada.
  if ($("#conteudo").is(':empty')){ //Se estiver vazia insiro a imagem clicada.
     $("#conteudo").append(novaImagem); //Atribui a nova imagem a div conteúdo.
     $("#conteudo").css("background-color", "#ff1"); //coloco a cor incial da div
  }else{ //Se possuir conteúdo limpo.
    $("#conteudo").empty()  //Limpa a div conteudo
     document.getElementById('conteudo').style.background='#fff'; //remove a cor da div
  }
}
```

```css
#conteudo{
      width:250px;
      height:250px;
      float:left;
      background-color:#ff1;  
      display: initial;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="conteudo" class="conteudo"> 
    <img src="https://png.icons8.com/view-as-different-user/ios7/50" />
    </div>
    <div id="lixoLimpaConteudo">
     <img src="https://png.icons8.com/view-as-different-user/ios7/50" onclick="alteraConteudo($(this))" alt="Limpar conteúdo" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Está perfeito !!
creio que seja este código que terei de estudar : 
.append(that);

Obg Caique!! Uma boa tarde :DD

Comment: pode me ajudar a entender o porque que a imagem a direita some ao clicar duas vezes? Pelo que estou estudando no código, era para limpar somente a div conteúdo certo??

Comment: Atualizei minha resposta para corrigir o problema.

Comment: Mt obg!!!! Solucionou minha questão !!